# How to know if a point belongs more or less to a circle?

Tags: geometry, circles, coordinate-systems

I know the formula to know if a point is inside, outside and on a circle : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/198769 This quote explains that we must compare `d` to `r` (please read the quote, **it's only 5 lines**).

**But I just want to know if a point is ON a circle**. Moreover, and that's the real problem : **if a point is A BIT inside/outside a circle, I WANT to consider it as ON the circle.**

How could I do that ? I tried to delimit `d-r` (ie. : the comparison) in a range. Example :

> if(d-r > -100 && d-r < 100) { point is on the circle }

It works, with -100 and 100, for circles with a little radius (ie. : ALL the points that are a bit outside/inside the circle are considered as being on the circle).

But for circles for a big radius, only SOME points are considered as being on the circle (ie. : only some of the points that are a bit outside/inside the circle are considered as being on the circle)...

**So I would want that ALL the points that are a bit outside/inside the circle are considered as being on the circle, independently of the circle's radius. How ?**

Comment: Perhaps the number that define the range (-100 or 100) can be dependent of the radius ? Perhaps I should multiply it by the radius. Edit : wrong idea. I tested, and even the very very very far points are detected as circle's ones...

Comment: You mean relative to the radius. So try doing something like $|d-r| < \epsilon r$, where $\epsilon$ is a small number, which you can adjust according to needed precision.

Comment: The test would be : `if(abs(d - r) < -ϵr)` ? - edit thanks

Comment: What are the minimal and maximal values you advise me for ϵ ? Because for values like 100, 50, 5 or even 1, all the points are considered as being on the circle, even very far ones

Comment: That would always be false as $\epsilon r > 0$. You try something like `if(abs(d - r) < ε r)`. And I do not have any experience with what you are working, so I don't have much idea sadly :)

Comment: Surely you must take $\epsilon < 1$! You do understand that setting $\epsilon = 1$ will cover the range of circle with radius $2r$!

Answer (score 0):

You must first define the maximal deviation =: $\varepsilon$ allowed.

If we denote:

d := Distance from center

Then you would have the pseudo code:

if(abs(d-r)$\le \varepsilon)${Point can be considered as being on the circle} with r being the radius of the circle.